# Apex to run cross-object duplicate detection (Leads vs Contacts)

Tags: leads, duplicate-management, database, cleanup

I have the following code that checks Phone, Phone2 and Mobile for Leads and gives an error if a Lead with the same phone exists, before saving the new record. How do I turn it into a code that will give me the same error if a Contact has the same phone number (the Lead would be a duplicate of the existing Contact)?

```
    trigger Lead_Phone_Dup on Lead (before insert, before update){

Map<String, Lead> leadMap =new Map<String, Lead>();
for (Lead lead : System.Trigger.new)
{   
 if ((lead.Phone !=null) &&
       (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
         (lead.Phone != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Phone)))
    {
        lead.Phone= lead.Phone.replaceAll('[^0-9,+,/]', '');
     if (leadMap.containsKey(lead.Phone))
        {
            lead.Phone.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
            lead.Phone_2__c.addError('');
            lead.MobilePhone.addError('');
        }else{
            leadMap.put(lead.Phone, lead);
        }
   }



  if ((lead.Phone_2__c !=null) &&
       (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
         (lead.Phone_2__c != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Phone_2__c)))
    {
        lead.Phone_2__c= lead.Phone_2__c.replaceAll('[^0-9,+,/]', '');
     if (leadMap.containsKey(lead.Phone_2__c))
        {
            lead.Phone.addError('');
            lead.Phone_2__c.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
            lead.MobilePhone.addError('');
        }else{
            leadMap.put(lead.Phone_2__c, lead);
        }
   }   

 if ((lead.MobilePhone !=null) &&
       (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
         (lead.MobilePhone != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).MobilePhone)))
    {
     lead.MobilePhone= lead.MobilePhone.replaceAll('[^0-9,+,/]', '');
     if (leadMap.containsKey(lead.MobilePhone))
        {
            lead.Phone.addError('');
            lead.Phone_2__c.addError('');
            lead.MobilePhone.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
        }else{
            leadMap.put(lead.MobilePhone, lead);
        }
   }
}


for (Lead lead : [SELECT Phone FROM Lead
                  WHERE Phone IN :leadMap.KeySet()])
{
    Lead newLead = leadMap.get(lead.Phone);
    newLead.Phone.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
    newLead.Phone_2__c.addError('');
    newLead.MobilePhone.addError('');
}

for (Lead lead : [SELECT Phone_2__c FROM Lead
                  WHERE Phone_2__c IN :leadMap.KeySet()])
{
    Lead newLead = leadMap.get(lead.Phone_2__c);
    newLead.Phone.addError('');
    newLead.Phone_2__c.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
    newLead.MobilePhone.addError('');
}

for (Lead lead : [SELECT MobilePhone FROM Lead
                  WHERE MobilePhone IN :leadMap.KeySet()])
{
    Lead newLead = leadMap.get(lead.MobilePhone);
    newLead.Phone.addError('');
    newLead.Phone_2__c.addError('');
    newLead.MobilePhone.addError('Duplicate warning: This or another existing Lead has the same Phone/Mobile number.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have created separate Duplicate Rules for each set of fields.

For example:

- 1 rule that compares Email(Lead) with Email (Contact).
- and 1 rule that compares Email (Lead) with Email2 (Contact).